# How can I detect when an app opens with bash? Is there an event with trap?

Tags: bash

I want to detect if an app opens with bash. I also want its PID.

I think it has something to do with `ps -ax`

Comment: You can periodically run a `ps` listing. If the process you want wasn't in the listing before, and it is now, that means it must have started between these two invocations. Parsing the PID out of the listing should be trivial to google.

Comment: I'd recommend `pgrep appName` instead of `ps | grep appName | cut ...`.